# What is forward moneyness and how to calculate it?

Tags: implied-volatility

I'm now studying the concept "implied volatility", and my teacher gave us a figure about the implied volatility with respect to the moneyness which is expressed by                                                           $\frac{ln(\frac{F}{K})}{\sigma\sqrt{T}}$
, where $F$ should be the forward price at maturity of the underlying I think?

Based on my knowledge, the moneyness should be
$\frac{S}{K}$

Could anyone tell me the meaning of the upper expression and the differences between these two kinds of moneyness?

Comment: How to find $F$ ?  If the stock pays no dividend then $F=S e^{r T}$.

Comment: There might be a typo. It Should be probably have been $ln(F/K)$. Then the upper expression is known as the standardized momeyness

Comment: Thanks for point out the typo, I've already edited it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of moneyness is not completely standardized, you can see different definitions in the literature:

- the simple moneyness is $\frac{S}{K}$ (in some cases you will see $\frac{K}{S}$)
- the log moneyness is $\ln \frac{S}{K}$
- the standardized log moneyness$\frac{\ln(S/K)}{\sigma\sqrt T}$

If the forward price $F$ is used in place of the underlying price $S$ you have (three definitions of) the *forward moneyness*. The forward moneyness is useful because it is more consistent with the way the Black Scholes formula works, it is more natural.

How to find $F$ ?  If the stock pays no dividend then $F=S e^{r T}$. You can also find $F$ by comparing the prices of puts and calls.